# Does intern() ever create a literal in the pool?

Tags: java, string, string-literals, string-interning

```
String s1=new String("abcd");
s2=s1.intern();
```

it is said that `intern()` will create a string literal in the pool if it is not already present.

My question is when will this scenario arise that string object is present but not the literal? And the intern() will have to actually go and create a new literal and then return the reference to literal.

Comment: We don't want to put *every* string into string pool. Storing string in pool makes sense only if you are going to reuse this string later, for instance it applies to string literals which you created in code where you may need it many times like `for (i..){ System.out.print("write your number:"); array[i]=readNumber();}`. But if you are reading some text from outside source like file/console/socket/other like line-by-line you don't really want to make JVM remember all of such lines. You may only want to print them once and let GC remove them from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
String first = "ab";
String second = "cd";
String interned = first.concat(second).intern();
```

Most of the strings in a program are dynamically created: by concatenating values, receiving them over a socket, reading them from files or databases, or from the console or a GUI.

Note that your terminology is wrong. `intern()` doesn't create a String literal. It adds a String to the pool, and String literals (i.e. Strings appearing *literally* in the byte-code, like `"abcd"`), are stored in the pool, along with explicitly interned Strings.

Comment: Is it possible to control which strings go in the pool?
My understanding is that every String should be in the pool.

Comment: String literals are in the pool. Other Strings are not, unless you intern them. Why in hell would you want to put all the strings into the pool? Let's say you read a 1GB file line by line to extract some data and write the data to another file. You would then need 2GB of memory to store all those lines in memory, for nothing: you'll never reuse those lines again.

Comment: You don’t need 2GB of memory; adding a string to the pool doesn’t imply the creation of a new instance—that’s implementation specific. You might receive the same instance, now being a member of the pool. More important, even after adding strings to the pool, they still can be garbage collected. So the memory consumption wouldn’t change. Still, adding these temporary strings to the pool creates an overhead without any benefit, as interning requires some kind of lookup, e.g. hashing, and the garbage collector may have additional work for clearing the pool’s references.